# How to correlate two x-y datasets with polynomial regression?

Tags: javascript, object, dataset, regression

I have two x-y datasets that form two potentially related scatter plots.

The first dataset has an approximate domain of 0 to 25,000 and range of 0 to 0.3. 
The second dataset has an approximate domain of 0 to 550 and range of 0 to 4.5. The first dataset is much more precise and can be considered correct, so I am trying to compaire the second set to the first to find out if the two sets correlate. The second set is also an inverse of the first.

Visualization of first dataset:
[image: pic1]

Visualization of second dataset:
[image: pic2]

The data is stored in the form of  `data: { xAxis: [0,1,2,3,4...], yAxis: [0.20779456198215485, 0.20824825763702393, 0.20915564894676208, 0.20960935950279236...] }` for each dataset.

**Approach:**

I am having trouble figuring out how to approach this problem. My initial thoughts are to reduce the first dataset by making it less precise in terms of data points, so removing ~20,000 data points with even spacing or something. I could split the graphs into periodic fragments and then use something like [regression-js](https://github.com/Tom-Alexander/regression-js) to do a 3rd degree polynomial regression with `regression.polynomial(data[, options])` and compare the regression constants of the two functions to see how much they correlate. However, this could be a completely incorrect approach by someone more experienced.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sorry but what *correlate* you want?

Comment: Imagine an assembly line has 10 stages, where dataset1 is a detailed scan of the 10th (final) stage, and dataset2 is a brief scan of the 3rd stage. Each dataset pair will have different but similar values with time. I want compare data at different times to see if there is a correlation with the 3rd and 10th stage or to see if it just looks like a correlation but is actually completely unrelated.

Comment: well, that's what I ask. what *correlation* you want? afaict this two are not really correlate. Anyway, maybe you can first try normalize the domain (time) to [0,1] (start and end) or something?

Comment: I suppose I am trying to overlay the data a closely as I can, then use the same constants that allowed the two graphs to overlay on a new dataset1 and dataset2 to see if the same regression constants can be used for any number of 'n' dataset pairs. If you invert the second graph you will notice that there are 5 local maxes, just as there are in the first graph.

Comment: what if it has 6 peak?

Comment: I would trim the beginning and end and associate those trends as noise.

Comment: I may take it wrong, but to clarify. I mean what if the data does not even **visually** related? not the peak in you example. (or they are actually unrelated)

Comment: The datasets will always resemble the pattern in the post.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the majority of the data is redundant. If you trim the top and bottom 1 or 2 percent from each of these two data sets you have not deleted any useful information, but have vastly reduced the data set size. It appears to me that the transitions between two states in each data set are the entirety of the information content.

Comment: You would be correct; I'm now thinking a potential way to compare these lines would be to find the transition points on the x axis for each curve/dip and find the n-th degree polynomial regression fit curve for said dip. This polynomial will give you 'n' coefficients which can then be compared to the equation and coefficients for the other graphs dip polynomial. You could then find some kind of deviation between the constants.